# How to pass dynamic url to gmail viewAction method of Go-to Action using magento?

Tags: magento, gmail

I am new for development. I want to develop Tracking order Button in gmail account subject. Like below image[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgx0P.png)

Example: code.gs

```
    function testSchemas() {
  var htmlBody = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('mail_template').getContent();

  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(),
    subject: 'Tracking Order status in the Inbox - ' + new Date(),
    htmlBody: htmlBody,
  });
}
```

mail_template.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="application/ld+json">
    {
      "@context": "http://schema.org",
      "@type": "EmailMessage",
      "potentialAction": {
          "@type": "ViewAction",
          "target": "https://checkout.example.com/sales/order/view/order_id/1666039/",
          "name": "Track Order"
  },
  "description": "See the order status"
}

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      This a test for a Go-To action in Gmail.
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

How to pass dynamic value for target attribute?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Same problem i am also facing..

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pattern in your email template and replace the value before sending the email.

For example: 
In mail_template.html

```
https://checkout.example.com/sales/order/view/order_id/{orderId}/
```

In testSchemas()

```
var htmlBody = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('mail_template').getContent();  
htmlBody = htmlBody.replace(/{orderId}/g, idOfTheOrder);
```